# NativeScript MaskedInput databinding

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to use the MaskedInput widget (https://github.com/bthurlow/nativescript-maskedinput) and I am having trouble getting the databinding to work.  Here is my code:

```html
<mi:MaskedInput mask="999 999 9999" placeholder="_" text="{{ customer.homephone }}" color="#a8b4b9" />
```

The above snippet does not display the phone number initially.  I am positive the customer.homephone has value in it because

```html
<TextField text="{{ customer.homephone, customer.homephone | phoneConverter() }}" class="value bold" />
```

displays it correctly.  If I replace the text property of the MaskedInput with a hard-coded value, the value is displayed.  It seems to me that there is something going on with the databinding.  Am I missing something here?

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing things correctly, but from what I see from the code of that plugin it does not support data binding.

Comment: Thank you Peter.  I did not even think about checking this.  I would assume that databinding is a must now a days.