# Nativescript Observable.propertyChangeEvent

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to create some customer formatting on a field (to reproduce a masked text box functionality).

I have an observable and I am capturing the propertyChange Event.  My question is:  Can I modify the value of the observed property inside the event handler without entering in an infinite loop?

Here is my code:

```js
model.customer.addEventListener(Observable.propertyChangeEvent, function(data) {
 if (data.propertyName.toString() === 'homePhone') {
      //Here is where I would like to change the value without triggering the event again
      //The below code does not seem to be working
   data.value = formatPhone(data.value);
 }
});
```

I looked at https://github.com/bthurlow/nativescript-maskedinput, but unfortunately this module does not support databinding.

Thank you.  Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested nativescript-maskedinput in a sample application and I was able to bind text property of this custom view. In regard to that if you add addEventListener and want to update for example TextField text property manually I think that property won't be updated properly. In addition I am attaching some sample code. 
main-page.xml

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:mi="nativescript-maskedinput" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"/>
    <mi:MaskedInput mask="1-999-999-9999? x999" hint="1-555-555-5555" text="{{ masktext }}" placeholder="#" />

    <Button text="tapToView" tap="onTap" />
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

main-page.js

```
var observable_1 = require("data/observable"); // Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml 
var newObservable = new observable_1.Observable(); 
function navigatingTo(args) {
    // Get the event sender
    var page = args.object;
    newObservable.set('masktext', '');

    page.bindingContext = newObservable; 
} 
exports.navigatingTo = navigatingTo; 
function onTap(args) {
    var newvalue = newObservable.get('masktext');
    console.log('newValueget + ' + newvalue); 
    } 
exports.onTap = onTap;
```

Comment: I was not able to get this to work, but maybe I missed something.  Let me try again.  This would the easiest way to handle this scenario.

Comment: I tried again and it does not work for me.  The initial data is not displaying.  I know I have data because when I use a regular TextField, I see it.  Actually, if you look at the response I got from Peter Stoev at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017201/nativescript-maskedinput-databinding, it looks like databinding is not enabled.
I have sibmitted an issue with the developer, but have not gotten a response yet.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible to override the getter, but if it is not possible you can do this:

```js
function isPhoneFormatted(phone) {
//your algorithm wich return true or false
}

model.customer.addEventListener(Observable.propertyChangeEvent, function(data) {
 if (data.propertyName.toString() === 'homePhone') {
      //Here is where I would like to change the value without triggering the event again
      //The below code does not seem to be working
   if (!isPhoneFormatted(data.value)) {
   data.value = formatPhone(data.value);
   }
 }
});
```

Notice that it is not well tested!

Comment: Ok, so when I try to assign a new value to data.value, nothing happens.  Is this property readonly?